# Export a job in postgres to an other database (productive system)

Tags: postgresql, export, backup, schedule, pgagent

I have create a job via pgadmin in postgres. This is a test system. How can I export this job to a database on other computer (productive system)?

Greets

Benjamin

Answer (score 0):

pgAgent stores data default in schema pgagent in database postgres. So you can dump and restore it.